# flutter column inside scaffold not accounting for top bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue with the widgets in my application starting from the top of the screen, underneath the top bar.

There is an official flutter thread about this where they just say "scaffold fixes this" and they closed the thread.  This might be true, but it is not working the way I am doing it.   So here is my code and the output:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Not sure how this is supposed to work, and can't find any working examples online.

Comment: Try with  SafeArea

Comment: If you want to avoid the status bar you should use `SafeArea`, but if you want to know status bar height you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `SafeArea` like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
        Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
        ],
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Yep, this seems to work.  You just have to add child: in front of column there for syntax but that works fine now.   Thank you!

Comment: @bisclavret You are right, but I was not in the editor or IDE